# php regex to detect if a url path has folder names

Tags: php, regex

One of the things I've really trouble is with regex, I just dont understand it :-(

So, I just need to check if one url has or not folder names after `.com` or `.net` or `.whatever` and if it has, isolate them in a variable, example

`www.mysite.com` (perfect) and `www.mysite.com/folder` or `http://mysubdomain.mysite.com/folder/folder`

the goal is to be able of isolate the folder names in a variable to be used as a path for upload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) more easily for that.

```
print_r(parse_url("http://mysubdomain.mysite.com/folder/folder"));
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => mysubdomain.mysite.com
    [path] => /folder/folder
)
```

And then just take the `path` out of that.

Answer (score 5):

Use PHPs `parse_url()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Thanks for help, your answer is correct, like mario answer too, thanks both for solvisg this :-)